# Safari - open tab in last position

Tags: macos, mac, tabs, safari

I'm using Safari 6.0.5 on Mac OS X 10.8.4.

Is it possible to configure Safari so that new tabs are opened not next to the current tab but at the end? Something similar to the Firefox option `browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent`.

I've searched everywhere with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an OSX user, but let's try this one for the fun of it.

You will need to write a script and bind it to a key.
Here is my attempt at the script :

```
tell application "Safari"
    if windows is {} then
        make new document
    else
        tell first window
            if miniaturized then
                set miniaturized to false
            end if
            make new tab at end with properties {URL:"<something>"}
            set current tab to last tab
            tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" to tell menu bar 1 to tell menu bar item "File" to tell menu 1 to click menu item "Open Location…"
        end tell
    end if
end tell
```

I am not sure that the "Open Location…" part is really necessary.

The resources I used to construct this answer from are :

[Open new tab in Safari on the left Web Browsers](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20130806104605997)
[How to open a new window and multiple urls in Safari with apple script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706171/how-to-open-a-new-window-and-multiple-urls-in-safari-with-apple-script)

This is as far as I can go without a Mac to try it on.

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension created for this case: [OpenAtEnd](http://lrasinen.kapsi.fi/OpenAtEnd/).

Comment: Unfortunately this extension is not supported any more...